# JavaFXPorts application code is not in apk

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, javafx, javafxports

I am trying my first JavaFX application on android using JavaFXPorts from Gluon. Unfortunately I am not able to build an apk containing application code. This is true with both my own projects and examples such as 2048FX by Jose Pereda http://jperedadnr.blogspot.com/2015/03/javafx-on-mobile-dream-come-true.html.

When I inspect the apks i generate, i cannot find any classes i created in the project. I do find any required SDK classes and application resource files. However there are no application specific *.class files.

I am creating the apks using gradle's 'android' task.

Below is a sample of my two gradle files. Displays is a dependency of TickerUI.

**Displays - build.gradle**

```
group 'com.androidtest'
version '1.0'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.9.9'
}

retrolambda {
    jdk 'C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_75\\bin'
    oldJdk 'C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_65\\bin'
    defaultMethods true
    incremental false
}
```

**TickerUI - build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.6'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'
apply plugin: 'idea'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

mainClassName = 'com.androidtest.ticker.tickerui.Main'

dependencies {
    compile files('../../Displays/Displays/build/libs/Displays-1.0.jar')
}

jfxmobile {
    android {
        androidSdk = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Android\\android-sdk'
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
```

**Note**
I am in the process of migrating my personal Nexus at home, which is why I am using a local file dependency.

**Java Versions**
Here are my versions of Java.
Intellij: 1.8.0_65 x64
Gradle: 1.8.0_65 x64
SDK: 1.8.0_65 x64.
Android SDK: 24.4.1 (x86?)
I tried switching to x86 versions of java but I was receiving a dex error. "could not initialize vm, not enough space for object heap.".

If anyone has any suggestions I would really appreciate it. Thank you in advance,

Jec

**Edit 1**
I did not see any errors within the ./gradlew.bat --info android command. However when I installed my TickerUI application on my phone and attached a debugger I received the following error:

```
12-18 08:33:33.237  18295-18295/com.androidtest.tickerui E/DalvikLauncher﹕ Launch failed with exception.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.androidtest.tickerui.Main" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.androidtest.tickerui-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.androidtest.tickerui-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at javafxports.android.DalvikLauncher.resolveApplicationClass(DalvikLauncher.java:264)
        at javafxports.android.DalvikLauncher.launchApp(DalvikLauncher.java:164)
        at javafxports.android.FXDalvikEntity.getLauncherAndLaunchApplication(FXDalvikEntity.java:119)
        at javafxports.android.FXDalvikEntity.surfaceCreated(FXDalvikEntity.java:145)
        at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:607)
        at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:184)
        at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:921)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2164)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6642)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.androidtest.tickerui.Main
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 23 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

I inspected my TickerUI.apk and I do see two .dex files inside the package. I'm not sure why android is not locating my Main class.

**Edit 2**

I'm starting to suspect my android manifest is the issue. It is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.androidtest.tickerui" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
        <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
        <application android:label="TickerUI" android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
                <activity android:name="javafxports.android.FXActivity" android:label="TickerUI" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
                        <meta-data android:name="main.class" android:value="com.androidtest.tickerui.Main"/>
                        <meta-data android:name="debug.port" android:value="0"/>
                        <intent-filter>
                                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                        </intent-filter>
                </activity>
        </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Usually all class files are bundled within the dex files. Can you deploy your app on your mobile? Do you have any error? Try to run`./gradlew --info android` and post the stack trace if you find any exception.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly Jose. I tried what you suggested on the 2048FX Project. That project is working as expected and runs on my phone perfectly. I didn't realize classes were located in .dex files within the APK. So that verifies that my local toolkits are working. I will try my project shortly.

Comment: See Edit 1. I found no stack traces in my ./gradlew --info android execution. The .dex files are in my apk but android cannot locate my Main for some reason. I'm going to read through my console output now. Thanks again Jose.

Comment: In your script you set your main class `'com.androidtest.ticker.tickerui.Main'`, while the exception complains about a different class: `'com.androidtest.tickerui.Main'`. Have you changed it? Check the AndroidManifest.xml file as well.

Comment: I did do a refactor a few days ago. Let me check.

Comment: That was it. My manifest was pointing to the wrong class. Thank you so much Jose!

Comment: Provide your solution as an answer to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the wrong main class specified in my android manifest. Thank you for the help José.